# Why does lazy regex capture extra words?

Tags: python, regex

I am using following lazy regex to find word before and after "=". I am not sure why it capturing extra words

```
r'\s+(.*?)\s+\=\s+(.*?)\s+'
```

The text is in format

```
my name = jil
part = #2
```

So I want to capture name = jil

am i doing something wrong here or can I do it in different manner.

Note : Before and after "=" we can have special characters

Comment: i think you need `\s+(.*?)\s+\=\s+(.*?)$` and you need to access the second capturing group..you are making `\s` a compulsion

Comment: What function are you using? `re.search(your_regex, "my name = jil smith")` captures `name` and `jil`.

Comment: @chepner it will fail on `re.search(your_regex, " my name = jil smith ")` it only works in your example because there are no spaces before `my` or after `smith`

Comment: @rock321987 your regex will match `dog dog dog dog dog` and `cat cat cat cat` from `dog dog dog dog dog = cat cat cat cat` and won't work. I haven't had much success with lazy matching in python... I much prefer using `\w`

Comment: What did you get from the regex? What was wrong?

Comment: I have lot of text and most of time it works fine but sometimes it captures extra text . I really don't understand what wrong here. I just want to capture any STRING before and after '=' sign.

Comment: you can use what i pointed above `(\S+)\s+\=\s+(\S+)`

Comment: @rock321987 i think u r wrong + is compulsion so I guess i wrong . 1=2 will not be captured correctly. ##TemporalWolf your answer seems right but how can i cater for special character.

Comment: I updated my answer, it should work with special characters

Comment: @TemporalWolf The question specifically asks why it captures *extra* words, not failing to match anything.

Comment: why is this question down voted . ?

Comment: @chepner I've added the why, cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for:
`(\S+)\s*\=\s*(\S+)`

`\S` matches non-whitespace, and will allow for `./\#@&`, etc in the capture group.

`\w` matches only word characters, so this matches the last word before an equals and the first word after, with or without whitespace between the = if you change the `\s+` to `\s*`

**Why** it doesn't work is because it parses it left to right: When it finds any amount of whitespace `\s+` it begins sucking in all characters `.*?` until it finds a `" ="`. So it will match the whole line before the `" ="` after any whitespace character.

The lazy evaluation doesn't go back to find the smallest set it can, it just goes until it reaches the first complete match and stops:

```
dog dog dog dog = cat cat cat cat
```

a lazy capture of `\s+(.*?)\s+=`
gives: us `dog dog dog`, because that's the first match it got: starting from a `" "` after the first dog and ending at the first `" ="` it finds. The second group does what you expect, because it doesn't have the extra requirement that it ends on a space with an equals sign.

After the `=`, the lazy will limit it to only the first word, as that is the first point at which it gets a match. A greedy version would continue sucking in characters and find the longest string which ends in `\s+`.

**tl;dr**: lazy evaluation won't go back to find the smallest match, it will grab the first match when parsing from left to right. `d+?og` will match `ddddddog` in it's entirety, as it needed to gobble all the other `d`s to match the first `d` with the `og` and it's too *lazy* to go back and see if it really needed to eat all those extra characters.

Comment: the word before and after can have special character like '.' , '#' '&' @TemporalWolf

Comment: Then use `\S` for non-whitespace. I'll update my answer

Comment: I marked you answer correct. Thank everyone been struggling for 2 hours on Sunday morning